# OSX 10.6 gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS, KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, xcode4.6

I have developed an application that is built in Xcode 4.6 with the base SDK set to 10.8 and deployment target set to 10.6. All my xib files have deployment target 10.6 and my dependencies are built and configured for 10.6.

The application runs just fine in 10.8 and 10.7, but when I install it on 10.6 it crashes immediately (it never appears in the dock) and I get the following error.

```
Process:         My App [9397]
Path:            /Applications/My App.app/Contents/MacOS/My App
Identifier:      com.mycompany.myapp
Version:         0.4.b (0.4.b)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [161]

Date/Time:       2013-03-11 13:57:31.613 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a2922e -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 416
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a2901b -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 259
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a28406 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 336
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a26a91 loadNib + 226
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a25fa1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 248
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a25dd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84a2335b NSApplicationMain + 279
8   com.mycompany.myapp             0x00000001000018b4 0x100000000 + 6324

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82964c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82966add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff829667b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff829662de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82965c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82965aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82965a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82965e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82965aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000100208c90  rbx: 0x0000000100208c90  rcx: 0x000003ffffffffff  rdx: 0x00000000ffffffff
  rdi: 0x0000000100208c90  rsi: 0x000000010023afd0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff4f0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff488
   r8: 0x00007fff709272a0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000010020cac0  r11: 0x00007fff5fbff3a0
  r12: 0x0000000000000010  r13: 0x0000000100230940  r14: 0x00000001000567a8  r15: 0x00007fff70929630
  rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100049ff7 +com.mycompany.myapp 0.4.b (0.4.b) <5B23E41F-0260-3387-A857-886B17CD2D77> /Applications/My App.app/Contents/MacOS/My App
       0x100076000 -        0x1000b2ff7 +com.github.ReactiveCocoa 1.0 (1) <7334C51B-6581-37CD-8DD1-AE63BE1D5714> /Applications/My App.app/Contents/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Versions/A/ReactiveCocoa
       0x1000e2000 -        0x100100ff7 +org.andymatuschak.Sparkle 1.5 Beta (git) (1.5) <1AEF9BA1-399F-37D5-B71C-E2B4BEF9B3AD> /Applications/My App.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
       0x10011b000 -        0x100121ff7 +com.septicus.SSCrypto 1.0 (1.1.2) <AE8B1882-A395-3F4A-B97C-77A2CE3973D9> /Applications/My App.app/Contents/Frameworks/SSCrypto.framework/Versions/A/SSCrypto
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3be0f  dyld 132.1 (???) <29DECB19-0193-2575-D838-CF743F0400B2> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80003000 -     0x7fff80009ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <8E302BB2-0704-C6AB-BD2F-C2A6C6A2E2C3> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff80182000 -     0x7fff801d1fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <1E2593D1-A7F6-84C6-DF8F-0B46AE445926> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff801d2000 -     0x7fff801e7ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <1AE1FE8F-2204-4410-C94E-0E93B003BEDA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff801e8000 -     0x7fff80307fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff80308000 -     0x7fff804c6ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4 (3.0.4) <0A4F51A1-4502-767B-8A4E-F14C6214EF88> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff80521000 -     0x7fff808befe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff808bf000 -     0x7fff808cefff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff80c74000 -     0x7fff80c74ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <23704665-E9F4-6B43-1115-2E69F161FC45> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff80ca5000 -     0x7fff80d66fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.6 (4.6.6) <BB2C5813-C61D-3CBA-A8F7-0E59E46EBEE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff80dc8000 -     0x7fff810c6fff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff81121000 -     0x7fff81123fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <CA8564FB-B366-7413-B12E-9892DA3C6157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
    0x7fff81124000 -     0x7fff81127ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <E03D7C81-A3DA-D44A-A88A-DDBB98AF910B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff811c4000 -     0x7fff811c9ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <4D84803B-BD06-D80E-15AE-EFBE43F93605> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff811ca000 -     0x7fff8124fff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff81373000 -     0x7fff8138cfff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <401557B1-C6D1-7E1A-0D7E-941715C37BFA> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff8138d000 -     0x7fff813caff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <F743389F-F25A-A77D-4FCA-D6B01AF2EE6D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff813d5000 -     0x7fff813d8ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <AEF55AF1-54D3-DB8D-27A7-E16192E0045A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff813d9000 -     0x7fff81489fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff8148a000 -     0x7fff81499fef  com.apple.opengl 1.6.13 (1.6.13) <516098B3-4517-8A55-64BB-195CDAA5334D> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff8149a000 -     0x7fff814e2ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <98FC4457-F405-0262-00F7-56119CA107B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff81651000 -     0x7fff8168bfff  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <539EBFDD-96D6-FB07-B128-40232C408757> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff816ad000 -     0x7fff816b2fff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <1D0D3531-9561-632C-D620-1A8652BEF5BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff816b3000 -     0x7fff816e4fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <7F102A07-E4FB-9F52-B2F6-4E2D2383CA13> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff816e5000 -     0x7fff816e5ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff817fd000 -     0x7fff817feff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <5952A9FA-BC2B-16EF-91A7-43902A5C07B6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff817ff000 -     0x7fff8197dff7  com.apple.WebKit 6533.21 (6533.21.1) <C89E93DE-3BFD-2E7A-2A49-356885FA1CDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
    0x7fff8197e000 -     0x7fff81dc1fef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff81dc2000 -     0x7fff81dd8fef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff81dd9000 -     0x7fff81ddefff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <201B8077-B5CC-11AA-E1B0-1D057ABE416A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff81de0000 -     0x7fff81ef7fef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <1B27AFDD-DF87-2009-170E-C129E1572E8B> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff81ef8000 -     0x7fff81f07fff  libxar.1.dylib ??? (???) <CBAF862A-3C77-6446-56C2-9C4461631AAF> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff81f3d000 -     0x7fff81f3dff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <4CCE5D69-F1B3-8FD3-1483-E0271DB2CCF3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff81f3e000 -     0x7fff81f87fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <1C050088-4AB2-2BC2-62E6-C969F925A945> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff8202e000 -     0x7fff82049ff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <9D50701D-54AC-405B-CC65-026FCB28258B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff8204a000 -     0x7fff8204aff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <68B0BE46-6E24-C96F-B341-054CF9E8F3B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff8205d000 -     0x7fff82131fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <C83E2BA1-1818-B3E8-5334-860AD21D1C80> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff82132000 -     0x7fff8293cfe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff8294b000 -     0x7fff82b0cfef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff82b23000 -     0x7fff82b2afff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4FF6AD25-0916-B21C-9E88-2CC42D90EAC7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff82b2b000 -     0x7fff82b3dfe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff82e98000 -     0x7fff82ebfff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <46A413EA-4FD1-A050-2EF0-6279F3EAD581> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff82ec0000 -     0x7fff831f4fef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff833a4000 -     0x7fff83421fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff83485000 -     0x7fff83485ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff83486000 -     0x7fff83516fff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff83517000 -     0x7fff8352dfe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff8352e000 -     0x7fff83542ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff83543000 -     0x7fff8365dfef  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <8A4B86E3-0FA7-8684-2EF2-C5F8079428DB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x7fff836a2000 -     0x7fff83860fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <4274FC73-A257-3A56-4293-5968F3428854> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff83da3000 -     0x7fff83dc6fff  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff83de3000 -     0x7fff83e20ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <4C3293E2-851B-55CE-3BE3-29C425DD5DFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff83e2d000 -     0x7fff83f12fef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff840cb000 -     0x7fff84209fff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <9DFE798D-AA52-6A9A-924A-DA73CB94D81A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff8420a000 -     0x7fff84906ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff84a21000 -     0x7fff8541bff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8541c000 -     0x7fff85593fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.5 (550.43) <31A1C118-AD96-0A11-8BDF-BD55B9940EDC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff855b7000 -     0x7fff855b8fff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff855c8000 -     0x7fff855d9ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <97019C74-161A-3488-41EC-A6CA8738418C> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff85643000 -     0x7fff85643ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <15DF8B4A-96B2-CB4E-368D-DEC7DF6B62BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff85644000 -     0x7fff85699ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <8807EB96-D12D-8601-2E74-25784A0DE4FF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
    0x7fff85710000 -     0x7fff8638bfef  com.apple.WebCore 6533.21 (6533.21.1) <15CE3700-C6DC-7F94-5394-4CF78040A40D> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
    0x7fff86465000 -     0x7fff864acff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <923E33CC-83FC-7D35-5603-FB8F348EE34B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff868f5000 -     0x7fff8693fff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <2EF19055-D7AE-4D77-E589-7B71B0BC1E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff86ab1000 -     0x7fff86ab5ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff86ab6000 -     0x7fff86ad6ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.12) <A4685F06-5881-35F5-764D-C380304C1CE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff86db6000 -     0x7fff86db8fff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <A9DB4D5D-4072-971B-DEF6-DDE645F415EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff86e22000 -     0x7fff86edffff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <BBB8888E-18DE-5D09-3C3A-F4C029EC7886> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff86ee7000 -     0x7fff86ef3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib 1.0.5 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB864FA-9197-5D48-A0EC-EC8330D475FC> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff86ef4000 -     0x7fff870e4fef  com.apple.JavaScriptCore 6533.20 (6533.20.20) <5626170D-00AE-33B1-03FF-256E9794150D> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
    0x7fff874d4000 -     0x7fff87534fe7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <4F071EF0-8260-01E9-C641-830E582FA416> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff87535000 -     0x7fff8753bff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff8753c000 -     0x7fff8757dfff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <78D48D27-A9C4-62CA-2803-D0BBED82855A> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8757e000 -     0x7fff8763ffff  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <A00BB0A7-E46C-1D07-1391-194745566C7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff87640000 -     0x7fff87693ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff87edf000 -     0x7fff87f5efe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff87f5f000 -     0x7fff87f7cff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <6D8E515B-E0A2-2BA1-9CAC-8CB8A8B35879> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff87f7d000 -     0x7fff87f7eff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <53299948-2554-0F8F-7501-04B34E49F6CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff8824f000 -     0x7fff88384fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <E5D7DBDB-6DDF-E6F9-C71C-86F4520EE5A3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff88385000 -     0x7fff88388fff  com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <BD1B0A22-1CB8-263E-FF85-5BBFDE3660B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff88414000 -     0x7fff884b4fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff884b5000 -     0x7fff88541fef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <3F1F2727-C508-3630-E2C1-38361841FCE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff887a2000 -     0x7fff88820ff7  com.apple.CoreText 151.10 (???) <54961997-55D8-DC0F-2634-674E452D5A8E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff8885f000 -     0x7fff8886aff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <3D65E89B-FFC6-4AAF-D5CC-104F967C8131> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff8886b000 -     0x7fff88905fe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.16 (???) <4B70A2FC-1902-5F27-5C3B-5C78C283C6EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff88906000 -     0x7fff889bcff7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff889bd000 -     0x7fff88a72fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <8C36373C-5473-3A6A-4972-BC29D504250F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff88a7b000 -     0x7fff88d04ff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <4419AFFC-DAE7-873E-6A7D-5C9A5A4497A6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff88d05000 -     0x7fff88d51fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff88d52000 -     0x7fff88d7afff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff88e07000 -     0x7fff88e14fe7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <1C35FA50-9C70-48DC-9E8D-2054F7A266B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff88e15000 -     0x7fff88e15ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <96FB6BAD-5568-C4E0-6FA7-02791A58B584> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff88e88000 -     0x7fff88e9cfff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff88e9d000 -     0x7fff88f56fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff88f7f000 -     0x7fff88fceff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <0731C40D-71EF-B417-C83B-54C3527A36EA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
    0x7fff88fdb000 -     0x7fff890b8fff  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff890b9000 -     0x7fff890dafff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F322F47-0584-CB7D-5B73-9EBD670851CD> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff8918a000 -     0x7fff891b5ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <8AB4CA9E-435A-33DA-7041-904BA7FA11D5> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff891b6000 -     0x7fff891c4ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff891c5000 -     0x7fff89200fff  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff89201000 -     0x7fff89242fef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff89243000 -     0x7fff89268ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff8945f000 -     0x7fff89465ff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff89466000 -     0x7fff896e8fe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.7 (751.62) <6F2A5BBF-6990-D561-2928-AD61E94036D9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff897f0000 -     0x7fff8985afe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <AF0EA96D-000F-8C12-B952-CB7E00566E08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8985b000 -     0x7fff89872fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <79AB2131-2A6C-F351-38A9-ED58B25534FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I ran the address at row 8 (Thread 0) through atos and got `start`, so I assume the crash occurs before any of my own code runs...

The whole day yesterday was spent researching the error but I am out of luck.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with help from [this thread at Cocoabuilder.com](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/325585-xcode-4-6-breaks-arc-on-snow-leopard.html).

You have to set `GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;` in your project settings, otherwise it won't run on 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/779846#779846) on the Apple Developer Forums:

> This is a known problem that we're tracking in 4.6.  We are aiming for
>   it to be fixed in a short-term 4.6.1 release, but do not have details
>   at the moment.  I'm sorry for this regression.